# backblaze seems to ignore path mtu - self build debian router has problems with too big packages

Tags: backblaze

The root cause of my problem seems to be too big packages:

```
17:55:29.577781 eth0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62820, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                         
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], cksum 0x9bde (correct), seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231592886 ecr 1643349940], length 1448                                    
17:55:29.577833 eth0  Out IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 59040, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 576)                                                                                                      
    #.#.#.# > 45.11.37.254: ICMP #.#.#.# unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1450), length 556                                                                                                           
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62820, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                                           
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231592886 ecr 1643349940], length 1448                                                            
17:55:29.798696 eth0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62821, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                         
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], cksum 0x9ba6 (correct), seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231592942 ecr 1643349940], length 1448                                    
17:55:29.798749 eth0  Out IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 59074, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 576)                                                                                                      
    #.#.#.# > 45.11.37.254: ICMP #.#.#.# unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1450), length 556                                                                                                           
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62821, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                                           
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231592942 ecr 1643349940], length 1448
17:55:30.254893 eth0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62822, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                         
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], cksum 0x9b34 (correct), seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231593056 ecr 1643349940], length 1448                                    
17:55:30.255241 eth0  Out IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 59143, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 576)                                                      
    #.#.#.# > 45.11.37.254: ICMP #.#.#.# unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1450), length 556                                                                                                           
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62822, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)                                                                                                                           
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231593056 ecr 1643349940], length 1448
17:55:31.152224 eth0  In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62823, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], cksum 0x9a54 (correct), seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231593280 ecr 1643349940], length 1448
17:55:31.152275 eth0  Out IP (tos 0xc0, ttl 64, id 59260, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 576)
    #.#.#.# > 45.11.37.254: ICMP #.#.#.# unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1450), length 556
        IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62823, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1500)
    45.11.37.254.443 > #.#.#.#.58708: Flags [.], seq 134:1582, ack 518, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 2231593280 ecr 1643349940], length 1448
```

But the fragmented packages never hitting the podman/host if I see it correctly.

I'll now try to force fragmentation and defragmentation. I think backblaze isn't reacting to icmp path mtu.

---

How can I debug a situation where partially data is dropped for some hosts?

- host run `curl https://www.google.com` - working
- container run `curl https://www.google.com` - working
- host run `curl https://s3.eu-central-003.backblazeb2.com/` - working
- container run `curl https://s3.eu-central-003.backblazeb2.com/` - not working

  - SSL hello from server is received but no data afterwards
- host run `nc -z s3.eu-central-003.backblazeb2.com 443` - working
- container run `nc -z s3.eu-central-003.backblazeb2.com 443` - working

More details can be found here:
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/16021

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I found another root cause and solution:
podman sets as default mtu 1.500. This leads to a mss(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_size) of also around 1.500. This of cause is more than the 1.450 which the router and host can talk. After changing the mtu via `ifconfig {interface} mtu 1450 up` the mss was correctly configured. The request comes through the network and everything works.

---

The question is a deadlock question :D

- Backblaze sends packages with 1.500 MTU
- Debian send icmp response
- Backblaze resends package with 1.500 MUT

After my knowledge this problem is only solvable on server-side and not client side.

I'll evaluate multiple options:

- http-proxy
- public ipv4 for all server
- socks-proxy

Comment: Thanks for posting the workaround. It looks like you're the same person that opened a support ticket on this issue - thanks for that, also!